# Agora Cloud Recording: Error 404 (Flutter + Google Cloud Function)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, agora.io

Currently having issues starting cloud recording for an Agora stream.

I'm using flutter and created a cloud function to start the recording.

Flutter:

```
 AgoraRtcEngine.onJoinChannelSuccess = (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) async {
  AgoraCloudRecording().startAgoraCloudRecording(channel, uid);
};
```

Cloud Function:

```
export async function retrieveAgoraToken(data: any){

//Variables
const channel = data.channel;
const uid = data.uid;


//AGORA KEYS
const agoraDoc = await agoraDocRef.get();
const appID = agoraDoc.data()!.appID;
const customerID = agoraDoc.data()!.customerID;
const secret = agoraDoc.data()!.secret;
const agoraCredentials = Base64.encode(customerID + ":" + secret);   

//AWS
const awsDoc = await awsDocRef.get();
const awsAccessKey = awsDoc.data()!.accessKey;
const awsSecretKey = awsDoc.data()!.secretKey;

const reqHeaders = {"Authorization": "Basic" + agoraCredentials, "Content-type": "application/json"};
const acquireReqBody = {
    "cname": channel,
    "uid": "1",
    "clientRequest": {
      "resourceExpiredHour": 24
    }
  };
console.log(reqHeaders);


//GET RESOURCE ID
const acquireURL = 'https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/' + appID + '/cloud_recording/acquire';
const acquireResourceID = {
    method: 'POST',
    url:  encodeURI(acquireURL),
    headers: reqHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(acquireReqBody)
}

const resourceIDRequest = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    request(acquireResourceID, function (error:any, res:any, body:any) {
      console.error('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', res && res.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
      resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      reject('error');
      });
  });

const resourceIDResponse = await resourceIDRequest;
console.log(resourceIDResponse);

const resourceID = resourceIDResponse.resourceId;

console.log(resourceID);

//START RECORDING
const recordingReqBody = {
    "cname": channel,
    "uid": "1",
            "clientRequest": {
              "recordingConfig": {
                "maxIdleTime": 30,
                "streamTypes": 2,
                "channelType": 1,
                "videoStreamType": 0,
                "transcodingConfig": {
                  "height": 640,
                  "width": 360,
                  "bitrate": 500,
                  "fps": 15,
                  "mixedVideoLayout": 1,
                  "backgroundColor": "#FF0000"
                },
                "subscribeVideoUids": [
                    uid
                ],
                "subscribeAudioUids": [
                    uid
                ],
                "subscribeUidGroup": 0
              },
              "recordingFileConfig": {
                "avFileType": [
                  "hls"
                ]
              },
      "storageConfig": {
        "accessKey": awsAccessKey,
        "region": 1,
        "bucket": "recorded-live-streams",
        "secretKey": awsSecretKey,
        "vendor": 1,
        "fileNamePrefix": [
          "directory1",
          "directory2"
        ]
      }
    }
  };

  
  const startRecordingURL = encodeURI('https://api.agora.io/v1​/apps​/' + appID + '​/cloud_recording​/resourceid​/' + resourceID + '​/mode​/mix/start');
  console.log(startRecordingURL);

  const startRecordingOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    url:  startRecordingURL,
    headers: reqHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(recordingReqBody)
}

const startVideoRecordingReq = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    request(startRecordingOptions, function (error:any, res:any, body:any) {
      console.error('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', res && res.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
      resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      reject('error');
      });
  });

const startVidRecordingResponse = await startVideoRecordingReq;

console.log(startVidRecordingResponse);
}
```

I've even tried to start recording adding token parameters.
I would generate the token via NodeJS with this library: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/tree/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/nodejs

I can successfully aquire the resourceID from Agora. However, if I try to start recording, I get a 404 error: 'no Route matched with those values'

Comment: To clarify and isolate the problem, can you get the same code working outside of Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [document](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/common_errors#:%7E:text=%22no%20Route%20matched%20with%20those,request%20to%20a%20wrong%20URL.) here that provides some context to the error you reported.

"no Route matched with those values": A possible reason for this message is that you entered an incorrect HTTP method in your request, such as using GET when it should have been POST. Another possible reason is that you sent your request to a wrong URL.

Comment: I'm using a POST method and the URL I have seems to be correct...

'https://api.agora.io/v1​/apps​/' + appID + '​/cloud_recording​/resourceid​/' + resourceID + '​/mode​/mix/start'

Comment: I got this error in `Query` api and there I changed the `Post` to `Get` then it gives response.
But I am getting response as `404: Resource not found`. If you have any idea regarding this please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to enable Cloud Recording on your project through the Agora Console.

To enable Cloud Recording on your project, visit https://console.agora.io/cloud-recording and select the **Project** name from the drop-down in the upper left-hand corner, click the *Duration* link below **Cloud Recording** and click the button to enable the service on that project.

[image: Screenshot of button to enable Agora Cloud Recording]

After you click *Enable Cloud Recording*, you will be prompted to confirm the concurrent channels settings which defaults to 50, click *OK*. Once enabled, you should see the usage graph enabled.

[image: Screenshot of Agora Cloud Recording usage graph enabled]